# How to fix Mario Golf 64 second player taunt glitch?

Tags: mario-golf

Trying to play Mario Golf 64 with my cousin. I used to own the game when I was younger.

A known glitch for it was that the second player would sometimes have its sound for taunts ramped down so you could barely hear it. I remember there was a fix for it, but I can't find it anymore anywhere on google.

Can anyone tell me how to fix the sound level on the second player so I can yell at my cousin, "Hurry up"?

Comment: The question says this is a known glitch, but I can't find any other reports of this online.

Comment: @Stevoisiak I recall finding something about it years ago. Are you experiencing the glitch as well?

Comment: I am not. I was browsing unanswered questions and came across this.